# how to make a button with a picture and text?

Tags: android, android-button

I need to create a button with the background and place it on the picture. I tried to create `LinearLayout Horizontal` bet on it, and put the background image and button. but it looks not nice. Tell me how to do this?
[image]

Comment: So, you tried. But what is your problem?

Comment: `it looks not nice` that is not an issue, there are ways to make it 'nice'

Comment: is that what I was trying to not give what I need. I want to button on the picture. I do not know how to do it

Comment: Could you please give me back my rating. This question has been helpful to me, and if there is an error I can fix it. select them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No layout is needed here, any TextViews can have [drawableLeft](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) attribute. Use appropriate XML attributes to set picture, padding, gravity of the text, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use button's xml attributes to set a drawable according to your need, and in your case it is drawableLeft. See the example below to make a think like your purpose :

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_btn"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/home_screen_sell_new_card_back_button_text"
    android:textColor="#026281"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And for the little enhancements, put paddings and other stuff.